# Openjpa-2.2.2-r422266:1468616 nonfatal user error caused by ArgumentException and InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException

Tags: postgresql, spring-data-jpa, openjpa

We have a web application run on tomcat and has code as below to find a schema entity.

```
@Override
public Schema findSchemaByCategoryAndDomainId(String category, Integer domainId) throws Exception
{
    return schemaDao.findByCategoryAndDomainId(category, domainId);
}
```

The database and ORM we used as follows

```
DataBase: PostgreSQL v9.4 (Windows version)
OpenJPA: version 2.2.2
SpringDataJPA: version 1.3.0.RELEASE
```

It works fine at the begining, but after amount of query have made, about 112000 times in 4 hours, it becomes failed and throw the exception as below:

```
[ERROR][datacollection.service.DataCollectionServiceImpl.postProbeData():711][16/06/15 11:53:27.147]
Exception: 
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter ParameterExpression<Integer> for query "null" exceeds the number of 2 bound parameters with following values "{ParameterExpression<Integer>=0, ParameterExpression<String>=PROBE_DATA}". This can happen if you have declared but missed to bind values for one or more parameters.; nested exception is <openjpa-2.2.2-r422266:1468616 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Parameter ParameterExpression<Integer> for query "null" exceeds the number of 2 bound parameters with following values "{ParameterExpression<Integer>=0, ParameterExpression<String>=PROBE_DATA}". This can happen if you have declared but missed to bind values for one or more parameters.
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:384)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(DefaultJpaDialect.java:122)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy104.findByCategoryAndDomainId(Unknown Source)
    at devicemanage.service.appdeploy.AdminServiceImpl.findSchemaByCategoryAndDomainId(AdminServiceImpl.java:2080)
    at devicemanage.service.appdeploy.AdminServiceImpl.findSchemaOIdByCategoryAndDomainId(AdminServiceImpl.java:2086)
    at devicemanage.service.appdeploy.AdminServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$76519d18.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:649)
    at devicemanage.service.appdeploy.AdminServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7f8fa940.findSchemaOIdByCategoryAndDomainId(<generated>)
    at datacollection.service.DataCollectionServiceImpl.postProbeData(DataCollectionServiceImpl.java:683)
    ...
Caused by: <openjpa-2.2.2-r422266:1468616 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: Parameter ParameterExpression<Integer> for query "null" exceeds the number of 2 bound parameters with following values "{ParameterExpression<Integer>=0, ParameterExpression<String>=PROBE_DATA}". This can happen if you have declared but missed to bind values for one or more parameters.
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ExpressionStoreQuery$AbstractExpressionExecutor.toParameterArray(ExpressionStoreQuery.java:423)
    at org.apache.openjpa.datacache.QueryCacheStoreQuery$QueryCacheExecutor.toParameterArray(QueryCacheStoreQuery.java:481)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:857)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:794)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingQuery.execute(DelegatingQuery.java:542)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:302)
    at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:330)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:123)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:55)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:95)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:85)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:312)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:266)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    ... 52 more
```

We have debugged it in debug mode, and it looks like the paramater String category and Integer domainId are both correct. After we have restart the tomcat, it works fine again. Is this a JPA issue or we need to tuning the JPA or database settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After we upgraded the spring-data-jpa lib to version `1.9.0.RELEASE` or later, the issue is solved. Under 8 asynchronous multi-thread query testing at each 200 ms one times.